# Is it possible for an app to use touch ID without the touch ID prompt or dialog?

Tags: ios, authentication

I have an app with a logon screen for the end user. I would like the user to either input a password or put their finger on the fingerprint sensor to unlock the app, without having iOS's built-in touch ID prompt appearing. Is this possible?

The logon screen is the first view controller on the navigation stack. When the view appears, I would like the user to be able to input the password or use the fingerprint reader to unlock the app (causing the next view controller to be pushed onto the navigation stack). Basically, I want to be able to use the fingerprint sensor without having the touch ID prompt from ever appearing.

Comment: Why do you want to hide the prompt?

Comment: I have a view controller to authenticate the user with a password/PIN. The iOS Touch ID prompt gets messy with navigation - for example with user logout, automatic logout while in background, and hitting the phone's Home button while the touch ID prompt is displayed (it dismisses the prompt, then you have to hit Home again to put the app in the background). It's just a bad user experience. It should be possible to have the Touch ID activate "automatically" (with no separate prompt) when an app's authentication view controller appears.